# what's the syntax error in these sas codes

Tags: syntax, sas

```
data work.totalsales;
 set work.monthlysales(keep = year product sales);
 retain monthsales {12};
 array monthsales {12};
 do i = 1 to 12;
 monthsales{i} = sales;
 end;
 count + 1;
 monthsales{count} = sales;
run;
```

I submit these codes. But it appears to have syntax problems. But where?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  It is unclear from your code.

Comment: Actually it comes from a multiple choice problem I saw on the book. The answer is "The program fails to execution due to syntax errors." I just don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax issue is the array style name in the `retain` statement.

Runtime error possible because `count` is not initialized.  If there are more than 12 records in "monthlysales" you will get an "array out of bounds" error on the 13th record.

Comment: Why we need to initialize `count`? Isn't set to zero at the beginning?

Comment: Technically it is missing.  The problem is that your count variable could exceed 12 (when the input data set has >12 records) which would then cause a runtime error when you tried to access slot 13 in an array with only 12 elements.